# How to remove Windows clutches from a NP-N150-JPB2US

Tags: bios, netbook

I'm in a developing nation trying to help a mother bring a netbook back to life so her son can use it for school.

It came with Windows 7, and it barely functions.

I'm trying to dual boot it with Linux Mint to let her try it out after totally rebuilding Windows.

Pressing F10/F12 takes it a Yukon PXE v6.63.1.3 screen that complains

```
PCE-E61 Media test failure, check cable
PCE-M0F Exiting PCE ROM
```

Holding Esc does nothing.

I have updated the BIOS to the latest on the website for an N150 Plus.

How can the BIOS be reached?

Comment: F10-12 tells it to boot from LAN or boot rom, see answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I'm seeing of others online the Samsung NP-150's BIOS can be reached via 'F2' while the boot menu (as you know) can be reached via the 'Esc' key.

http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/390

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1461860

http://forums.cnet.com/7723-19688_102-602077/does-the-samsung-n150-have-a-boot-menu/

Comment: That linux mint tutorial looks promising, EasyBCD.  I'll be back as soon as I can test.  Thank you.